# Getting First 5 Items from Observable that fetches data from a network call

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have the following code to fetch a list of items from the internet.

```
Observable<RealmList<Artist>> popArtists = restInterface.getArtists();
    compositeSubscription.add(popArtists.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(artistsObserver));
```

The trouble is the list has over 80 items and i only want to get the first 5 items. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: does the endpoint let you specify a limit or page size ?

Comment: `take(5)` on the Observable?

Comment: @cricket_007 `take(5)` worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`take`is the operator you looking for. (see documentation here : http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/take.html )

The `flatMapIterable` transform your `RealmList` (which implement `Iterable`, that's why `flatMapIterable` can be used) to an `Observable` which emiting all items of your list

```
Subscription subscription = restInterface.getArtists()
                                         .flatMapIterable(l -> l)
                                         .take(5)
                                         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                         .observeOn(androidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                         .subscribe(artistsObserver);

compositeSubscription.add(subscription);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have no control over server side, so solution is to take first 5 items from received result:

```
Observable<RealmList<Artist>> popArtists = restInterface.getArtists();
compositeSubscription.add(
popArtists.flatMap(list-> Observable.from(list).limit(5)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())                      
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(artistsObserver));
```